# ListView not refreshing on custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to refresh my `ListView` when a new message arrives, however I cannot seem to get the listview/adapter to refresh once the message has been added.  `NotifyDataSetChangers()` does not seem to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

**MessagingActivity**

```
public class MessagingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    UserCredentialHandler userCredentialHandler;
    ListView chatListView;

    List<ChatRowItem> chatRowItems;
    List<Message> messagesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messaging);
        userCredentialHandler = new UserCredentialHandler();
        Button bMsgJas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bJas);
        Button bMsgTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bTest);
        Button bSendMsg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send_message);
        final EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chat_enter_message);

        final String userH = "h@h.com";
        final String userT = "test@test.com";

        chatRowItems = new ArrayList<>();
        final ChatCustomAdapter adapter = new ChatCustomAdapter(this, chatRowItems);
        chatListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chat_listview);
        chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        chatListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        bMsgJas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SendBird.startMessaging(userH);
            }
        });

        bMsgTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SendBird.startMessaging(userT);
            }
        });

        bSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String newMsg = inputText.getText().toString();
                SendBird.send(newMsg);
            }
        });

        SendBird.setEventHandler(new SendBirdEventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(Channel channel) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChannelLeft(Channel channel) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(Message message) {
                messagesList.add(message);

                adapter.updateChatList(chatRowItems);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSystemMessageReceived(SystemMessage systemMessage) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBroadcastMessageReceived(BroadcastMessage broadcastMessage) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFileReceived(FileLink fileLink) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onReadReceived(ReadStatus readStatus) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTypeStartReceived(TypeStatus typeStatus) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTypeEndReceived(TypeStatus typeStatus) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAllDataReceived(SendBird.SendBirdDataType sendBirdDataType, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageDelivery(boolean b, String s, String s1, String s2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessagingStarted(final MessagingChannel messagingChannel) {

                SendBird.queryMessageList(messagingChannel.getUrl()).load(Long.MAX_VALUE, 30, 10, new MessageListQuery.MessageListQueryResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(List<MessageModel> messageModels) {
                         messagesList = (List<Message>)(List<?>) messageModels;
                         for(int i = 0; i < messageModels.size(); i++){
                             drawListRows(messagesList.get(i));
                         }
                        SendBird.join(messagingChannel.getUrl());
                        SendBird.connect();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessagingUpdated(MessagingChannel messagingChannel) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessagingEnded(MessagingChannel messagingChannel) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAllMessagingEnded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessagingHidden(MessagingChannel messagingChannel) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAllMessagingHidden() {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        //final String member_list_id = rowItems.get(position).bookListId;

    }

    public void drawListRows(Message msg){
        ChatRowItem item = new ChatRowItem(msg.getSenderName(), msg.getMessage(), msg.getTimestamp());
        chatRowItems.add(item);
    }

  //  public void updateChatList(List<ChatRowItem> chatItems){
  //      messagesList.clear();
  //      messagesList.addAll(newMsgList);
    }
```

**ChatCustomAdapter**

```
public class ChatCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<ChatRowItem> chatRowItemList;
    Context context;

    ChatCustomAdapter(Context context, List<ChatRowItem> chatRowItemList){
        this.chatRowItemList = chatRowItemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return chatRowItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return chatRowItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return chatRowItemList.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView username;
        TextView message;
        TextView timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null ) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.message = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_message_text);
            holder.username = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_user_id);
            holder.timestamp = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_timestamp);

            ChatRowItem row_pos = chatRowItemList.get(position);

            holder.message.setText(row_pos.message);
            holder.username.setText(row_pos.userId);
//            holder.timestamp.setText((int)row_pos.timestamp);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateChatList(List<ChatRowItem> chatItems){
        chatRowItemList.clear();
        chatItems.addAll(chatItems);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 chatItems.addAll(chatItems);
```

should be

```
 chatRowItemList.addAll(chatItems);
```

but that's not enough. `chatRowItemList.clear();` is removing all the items from `chatRowItems`, since you are passing it as reference to your Adapter's constructor.

Comment: Made the chatRowItemList correction, the list seems to be cleared but when it updates the list is empty.  I do not see how clear is modifying the chatItems constructor.

Comment: after `chatRowItemList.clear()` both `chatRowItemList` and `chatItems` are empty.

Comment: Does chatRowItemList.addAll(chatItems) not add a new list?

Comment: indeed and that's what it is doing. Check the content of both after you call clear. Print it in the log, just to try to understand

Comment: Ah I see, its just my listview just goes blank after I call the method so assumed it was not actually adding the new data.

Comment: in the Adapter's constructor do: `this.chatRowItemList = new ArrayList<>(chatRowItemList);` and try again

Comment: Tried that, did not do anything.

Comment: Correct, in this method:             @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(Message message) {
                drawListRows(message);
                adapter.updateChatList(chatRowItems);
            }

Comment: and from the Adpater's constructor  did you remove: `this.chatRowItemList = chatRowItemList;`?

Comment: Yup     
    ChatCustomAdapter(Context context, List<ChatRowItem> chatRowItemList){
            this.chatRowItemList = new ArrayList<>(chatRowItemList);
            this.context = context;
    }

Comment: Weird behaviour, when scrolling the adapter it worked (new message was added to the list) but when scrolling up and down the message disappeared.

Comment: those lines: `
            ChatRowItem row_pos = chatRowItemList.get(position);

            holder.message.setText(row_pos.message);
            holder.username.setText(row_pos.userId);` go outside the if/else in your getView

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the adapter again could solve

Comment: is not because your adapter is empty? I mean, first maybe you have to add the items to ArrayList, then instantiate the adapter and finally set it to the listView, like: chatRowItems = new ArrayList<>();  chatRowItems.add("some"); chatRowItems.add("some");
        final ChatCustomAdapter adapter = new ChatCustomAdapter(this, chatRowItems);
        chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);